# Why is this method not working?

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

I have this method :

```
private static string browse(Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Folder folder, 
 ClientContext ctx,ref StringBuilder str)
        {
            string folderName;
                str.AppendLine("browse" + folder.Name);

        ctx.Load(folder.Folders);

            ctx.ExecuteQuery();

            if (folder.Folders.Count > 0)
            {       
            for (var i = 0;i<folder.Folders.Count ; i++)
           {
                browse(folder.Folders[i], ctx, ref str);
                folderName = folder.Folders[i].Name;

            }
        }
        return folderName;

    }
```

When I call it, the folderName that it returns is an empty string and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 5):

First, your code will not compile since `folderName` might not be initialized before accessing it...

Secondly, the code runs fine on my end.. Are you sure your `folder` contains subfolders? (i.e. `folder.Folders.Count > 0` is really `true`?)

I used the following code - which uses yours only slightly (`string folderName = null;` instead of `string folderName;`) modified:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var url = "https://my.share.point/sites/asdf/";

    using (var ctx = new ClientContext(url))
    {
        var folder = ctx.Site.RootWeb.Lists.GetByTitle("Blubb").RootFolder;
        ctx.Load(folder);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        Console.WriteLine(browse(folder, ctx, ref sb));
        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
    }

    Console.WriteLine("done");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static string browse(Folder folder,
    ClientContext ctx, ref StringBuilder str)
{
    string folderName = null;
    str.AppendLine("browse" + folder.Name);

    ctx.Load(folder.Folders);

    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

    if (folder.Folders.Count > 0)
        for (var i = 0; i < folder.Folders.Count; i++)
        {
            browse(folder.Folders[i], ctx, ref str);
            folderName = folder.Folders[i].Name;
        }
    return folderName;
}
```

The list looks like this:
[image: Folder-Structure in my list]

and the outcome like this:
[image: Outcome of the code]

To explain this further I ["transplanted" your algorithm to ideone](http://ideone.com/nH9b2f). Have a look at it - there's nothing wrong with the algorithm itself (depending on what you were expecting).

Comment: Yes, there are subfolders in the SharePoint folder.
I tried calling the method like this: 
string fldname=browse(someFolder,ctx,ref str);
I wanted to print the result in console, but I don't get anything.

Comment: @angie: Well, your code is working fine. The Problem is somewhere else...

Comment: Can you try printing out in console the value of folderName that is returned when the method is called?

Comment: Well, it would only print output only for a folder with subfolders and in that case the name of the last subfolder. For folders without subfolders it will be empty.

Comment: It is  empty even though my folder has subfolders in it and when I tried to get the length of it, I got a System.nullReference exception.

Comment: @angie: See the code on ideone (http://ideone.com/nH9b2f) it *will return "something"* if your initial folder has at least one subfolder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62022/discussion-between-nils-and-angie).